# Subscript and Superscripts in CDATA of an xml file. Using UILabel to display the parsed XML contents

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, uilabel, cdata

I need to display subscripts and superscripts (only arabic numerals) within a UILabel. The data is taken from an XML file. Here is the snippet of XML file:

```
<text><![CDATA[Hello World X\u00B2 World Hello]]></text>
```

Its supposed to display X2 (2 as superscript). When I read the string from the NSXMLParser and display it in the UILabel, it displays it as X\u00B2. Any ideas on how to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do something like this, assuming the CDATA contents have been read into an NSString and passed into this function:

```
-(NSString *)removeUnicodeEscapes:(NSString *)stringWithUnicodeEscapes {
    unichar codeValue;
    NSMutableString *result = [stringWithUnicodeEscapes mutableCopy];
    NSRange unicodeLocation = [result rangeOfString:@"\\u"];
    while (unicodeLocation.location != NSNotFound) {

        // Get the 4-character hex code
        NSRange charCodeRange = NSMakeRange(unicodeLocation.location + 2, 4);
        NSString *charCode = [result substringWithRange:charCodeRange];
        [[NSScanner scannerWithString:charCode] scanHexInt:&codeValue];

        // Convert it to an NSString and replace in original string
        NSString *unicodeChar = [NSString stringWithFormat:%C", codeValue];
        NSRange replacementRange = NSMakeRange(unicodeLocation.location, 6);
        [result replaceCharactersInRange:replacementRange withString:unicodeChar];

        unicodeLocation = [result rangeOfString:@"\\u"];
    }

    return result;
}
```

I haven't had a chance to try this out, but I think the basic approach would work

Comment: Whoa. That's the right answer. Works like a charm. Thank you so much Tim.

Answer (score 1):

`\u00B2` is not any sort of XML encoding for characters. Apparently your data source has defined their own encoding scheme (which, frankly, is pretty stupid as XML is capable of encoding these directly, using entities outside of CDATA blocks).

In any case, you'll have to write your own parser that handles `\u####` and converts that to the correct character.

Comment: thanks Kevin for your input. I was kind of expecting it. Anyways will wait to see if anyone has miracle up their sleeve. If no other way out, will follow the way you recommended. BTW, being XML noobie, would you point me to how to do this "XML is capable of encoding these directly, using entities outside of CDATA blocks". I am at liberty to change the XML structure.

Comment: @Anshu: CDATA blocks are meant for embedding literal characters. The simplest thing to do might be to actually embed the literal superscript character in lieu of the \u00B2. If whatever you're using wants to stick to ASCII, then you can use an entity outside of a CDATA block, e.g. `<text><![CDATA[Hello World X]]>&#x00B2;<![CDATA[ World Hello]]></text>`. Granted, if you're encoding all non-ASCII chars as entities, you may as well stop using CDATA entirely (and make sure to encode `<` and `&` as entities too)

Comment: Unicode 00B2 is the superscript 2 character, and 00B3 is the superscript 3 character. This is not any kind of custom encoding scheme.

Comment: @TimDean: It is a custom encoding scheme. It's using the sequence `\u1234` in place of the actual unicode character 1234. This is not part of the XML spec, but is being created by the software that generates the XML. In other words, it's not something that an XML decoder is supposed to handle. Either you need to decode it on the receiving end, or you need to stop creating this on the sending end. The latter is preferable, because it's a *really stupid* way to try and encode non-ASCII characters, given the multiple legitimate ways you can do this that require zero work on the client.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the question to my colleague and he gave me a nice and simple workaround. Am describing it here, in case others also get stuck at this.

Firstly goto [this link](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/arial_unicode_ms/blockview.htm?block=superscripts_and_subscripts). It has a list of all subscripts and superscripts. For example, in my case, I clicked on "superscript 0". In the following HTML page detailing "superscript 0", goto "Java Data" section and copy the "⁰". You can either place this directly in XML or write a simple regex in obj-c to replace \u00B2 with "⁰". And you will get nice X⁰. Do the same fro anyother superscript or subscript that you might want to display.

Comment: <code>\u00B2<code> is superscript 2 and not superscript 0. But in any case, that's the idea.